# Adjusted the code of a recorded VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

im fairly new to VBA and need some help. I have a datafile containing about 500 tabs. These 500 tabs are organized by the state that they represent.

I recorded a macro to create format the table in tabs that contain the state of California. for reference, the table's headers start on row 11, and their state is specified in the "STATE" Columns (column 2). at the top of each datatable within these tabs, is a summary table (these are what need reformatting).

The tab names do not include their state information for reference.

I recorded a macro that will format the tab exactly how I need, but how can I adjust this macro to loop through all 500 tabs, and only adjust the tabs that have "California" listed in the tab's "STATE" column?

```
`Sub CL_Formatting()
'
' CL_Formatting Macro
'
 
'
    Range("A1:E9").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("B1:F9")
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A4")
    Range("A2:A9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("C9:F9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("B2:F2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("B2:F2,A2:A9,B9:F9").Select
    Range("B9").Activate
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B3:F8").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A2:A9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Range("A11:BQ11").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B13").Select
    Rows("11:11").RowHeight = 41.25
    Range("G20").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("I11"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Range("D14").Select
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 35.14
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 32.29
    Range("D3:E7").Select
    Range("E3").Activate
    Selection.Merge True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    Range("B3:B8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("F3").Select
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 41.86
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 46.29
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 47.43
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14.43
    Range("D7:E7").Select
End Sub`
```

I tried creating a loop that would loop through each tab and format the tabs that have "California" listed in their "State" Columns, however nothing would happen when I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Create another sub to loop through each sheet, check if the STATE column contains "California", then call the formatting macro, passing the sheet as an argument to the formatting macro.

```
Sub loop_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range

'Loop through each sheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    
    'Set range to "STATE" column from row 12 until last row in sheet
    Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Range("B12"), ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    'Check if any cell is "California", then call formatting macro
    If Not IsError(Application.Match("California", rg, 0)) Then
        Call CL_Formatting(ws)
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

You will have to update your `CL_Formatting` macro as follows:

Name it `Sub CL_Formatting(ws As Worksheet)` so it can accept the sheet as an argument

Add a line at the top `ws.activate` because your ranges are unqualified

Replace this part of the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("I11"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CL").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

With this:

```
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("I11"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This will get the macro running, but using `.Select` so often is not a good idea, and using unqualified ranges is also not a good idea, especially when looping through many sheets. Fixing those issues will make your code faster and more reliable.